# Is there a way to change the display name in email sent via Google Apps Script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I'm testing email sent from Google Apps Script and it's sending it with the display name of the email address (the part before the @).

It's a business address like: info@example.com and all that is showing is "info".

I would like to make it like: "Bob from Example.com"

Is there any way to do this in App Script? I have it set up for manually sent emails.

Thanks in advance. I couldn't find help from a Google search.

Comment: A generic example from what works (shows "Bob from Example Ltd" as sender): GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {'bcc':'info@example.com', 'name':'Bob from Example Ltd', 
'htmlBody':'<p>Hi ' + firstName + ',</p> <p>Just a little update to let you know that we have your job planned for <b>' + targetDate})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could do that with the advanced parameters of `sendEmail` method of `GmailApp` class.

`name` is the parameter you are looking for. 
Here is the code sample that Google provides.

```js
MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
});
```

Find more details here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: This does not address the case where multiple different users want to use this script, and want to have their names be uniquely identified.